# How would I do this in Java Regex?

Tags: java, regex

Trying to make a regex that grabs all words like lets just say, chicken, that are not in brackets. So like

```
chicken
```

Would be selected but

```
[chicken]
```

Would not. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: When did `foo` go out of style? :)

Comment: the chicken has probably crossed the road to meet it. anyway, for a really good learning and exercising of RegEx, I use this website: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String template = "[chicken]";
String pattern = "\\G(?<!\\[)(\\w+)(?!\\])";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(template);

while (m.find()) 
{
     System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

It uses a combination of [negative look-behind and negative look-aheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [boundary matchers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).

```
(?<!\\[) //negative look behind
(?!\\])  //negative look ahead
(\\w+)   //capture group for the word
\\G      //is a boundary matcher for marking the end of the previous match
```

> (please read the following edits for clarification)

**EDIT 1:**
If one needs to account for situations like:

```
"chicken [chicken] chicken [chicken]"
```

We can replace the regex with:

```
String regex = "(?<!\\[)\\b(\\w+)\\b(?!\\])";
```

**EDIT 2:**
If one also needs to account for situations like:

```
"[chicken"
"chicken]"
```

As in one still wants the `"chicken"`, then you could use:

```
String pattern = "(?<!\\[)?\\b(\\w+)\\b(?!\\])|(?<!\\[)\\b(\\w+)\\b(?!\\])?";
```

Which essentially accounts for the two cases of having only one bracket on either side.  It accomplishes this through the `|` which acts as an or, and by using `?` after the look-ahead/behinds, where `?` means 0 or 1 of the previous expression.

Comment: Why `.group(1)`? Why not just get rid of the group and use `.group()`?

Comment: @arshajii I have a save file that I use for SO regex questions, forgot to take it out.

Comment: Actually, wont this also match the `"hicke"` in `"chicken"`?

Comment: `\G` causes other problems; try this with `"chicken [chicken] chicken [chicken]"`. Only the first `"chicken"` will be picked up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34569/discussion-between-steve-p-and-arshajii)

Comment: @arshajii I think with my final edit that I have account for all possible cases, but I'm not 100%.

Comment: It works fine, but I have another question about regex.
Lets say I have the string "The x chicken", how would I check it with "x" being any string.

Comment: @Ultimate I'm glad, just make sure you read the two edits in case one of those edge cases is present.  If it's a short response, I don't mind answering, but if not, you should probably ask another question.

Comment: @Steve I haven't seen any edge cases yet.

Comment: @Ultimate I'm not entire certain what you mean by that.  I suggest refining it with an example and posting another question.  So long as you don't abuse/flood the system, asking multiple questions is fine and in fact recommended.  Moreover, it gives you the chance to gain more reputation.  Just make sure to put as much of an explanation as possible and also what you have tried.  It's okay that it didn't work, we know that by virtue of you asking the question.  Just show some effort, or people may downvote you. I think people didn't on this question because it was interesting and intriguing.

Comment: For the answerer who may be wondering, I downvoted this because the final solution isn't very readable/intuitive. I realize that's the nature of complicated regular expressions, but perhaps that means it's not quite the best tool for the whole job.

Comment: @jpmc26 Really?  He asked for regex, I gave him what he wanted and was downvoted because of it.  That actually makes no sense.  If you want to keep the downvote, then whatever, we each lose rep, but that makes no sense.

Comment: It's not about rep. It's about readability, which I consider an important factor in all code. The downvote button is there for me to express my opinion, and I explained it because StackOverflow encourages that the reason be voiced when a downvote is given. My opinion happens to be that the difficulty in reading the code is too high a price to pay to use regular expressions for the entire problem. The OP didn't indicate any kind of restriction that prevents the use of accompanying code, so I feel that's a better solution; obviously, I'm in the minority. I hope that clears it up for you.

Comment: @jpmc26 Apparently OP and the others who upvoted disagree, but as you said, we're all entitled to our opinions.  On that note, see [Privileges-vote down](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).  It clearly states that what you did here is not what down voting was intended for; nonetheless, you are entitled to do it.

Comment: @jpmc26 Usually for this type of grievance, one would simply post a comment.

Comment: You are correct. My apologies. StackOverflow is telling me that I cannot remove the downvote unless the answer is edited. If you can think of something to edit, I will remove it. I feel like I should point out that it was never something personal.

Comment: @jpmc26 I understand.  I'll make an edit so that you can remove it.  Thanks.

Comment: @jpmc26 Damn, you're fast.

Comment: @jpmc26 For what it's worth, I agree that this solution is unnecessarily convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like:

```
final Pattern UNBRACKETED_WORD_PAT = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\[)\\b\\w+\\b(?!])");

private List<String> findAllUnbracketedWords(final String s) {
    final List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Matcher m = UNBRACKETED_WORD_PAT.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        ret.add(m.group());
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(ret);
}
```

Comment: Note that this would not match `[chicken` (only one `[`, no `]`).

Comment: @Qtax: Yes, good point. I'm not sure if that's a problem; the OP has given very little information. (That's why my answer starts with "I guess you want". :-P )

Comment: Why don't you make your `findAllUnbracketedWords()` method `public final` while you're at it. ;-p

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
/(?<![\[\w])\w+(?![\w\]])/
```

i.e., consecutive word characters with no square bracket *or* word character before or after.

This needs to check both left and right for *both* a square bracket *and* a word character, else for your input of `[chicken]` it would simply return

```
hicke
```

Answer (score 0):

Without look around:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MatchingTest
{
    private static String x = "pig [cow] chicken bull] [grain";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[?)(\\w+)(\\]?)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
        while(m.find())
        {
            String firstBracket = m.group(1);
            String word = m.group(2);
            String lastBracket = m.group(3);
            if ("".equals(firstBracket) && "".equals(lastBracket))
            {
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
pig
chicken
```

A bit more verbose, sure, but I find it more readable and easier to understand. Certainly simpler than a huge regular expression trying to handle all possible combinations of brackets.

Note that this won't filter out input like `[fence tree grass]`; it will indicate that `tree` is a match. You *cannot* skip `tree` in that without a parser. Hopefully, this is not a case you need to handle.